# Android error in java InputStreamReader only with Huawei phone

Tags: android

I'm facing this strange (to me) error in my android application. 
I've installed this app on many devices (Galaxy SII, Google Nexus, Google Nexus S) and it works perfectly.
But with an Huawei phone, the app crashes at the beginning, when I get data from server.

The log of this error is:

```
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862): a java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862): at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):at java.util.Calendar.getHwFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.java:822)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at java.util.Calendar.<init>(Calendar.java:753)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:338)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:239)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1152)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils.<clinit>(DateUtils.java:81)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicExpiresHandler.parse(BasicExpiresHandler.java:58)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.CookieSpecBase.parse(CookieSpecBase.java:95)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.NetscapeDraftSpec.parse(NetscapeDraftSpec.java:144)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BestMatchSpec.parse(BestMatchSpec.java:125)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies.processCookies(ResponseProcessCookies.java:120)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies.process(ResponseProcessCookies.java:101)
06-05 10:36:25.312: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:304)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.postProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:319)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at it.mio.miaapp.SplashScreenActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivity.java:225)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at it.mio.miaapp.SplashScreenActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivity.java:1)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-05 10:36:25.315: W/System.err(20862):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-05 10:36:25.318: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:25.325: W/System.err(20862): Illegal: "<" inside attribute value (position:START_TAG <carrierweek numeric='20416' carrier='T-mobile' firstdayofweek='1'>@35:5 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41bfef18) 
06-05 10:36:25.332: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:25.335: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:25.342: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:25.345: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:25.595: E/dalvikvm(20862): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3044K, 17% free 17908K/21319K, paused 2ms+3ms
06-05 10:36:25.812: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:25.832: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:25.832: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:25.835: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:25.885: E/dalvikvm(20862): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5846K, 26% free 17411K/23495K, paused 2ms+3ms
06-05 10:36:26.042: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:26.072: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:26.108: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:26.115: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:26.172: E/dalvikvm(20862): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2180K, 16% free 19767K/23495K, paused 2ms+4ms
06-05 10:36:26.275: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:26.295: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:26.305: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 10:36:26.305: W/System.err(20862): /data/system/carrierinfo.prop: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The line of the code involved inside an AsyncTask to retrieve the data from server is:

```
response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
```

Any clue? 
The app doesn't work only on Huawei.

Comment: What should return uri[0]? An int? 
The error is simple, there is some place that expect an int,( from Calendar!?) and on Huawei, that value is empty "".

Comment: No. It returns a String.

Comment: Have you any idea to solve this problem? How a value of the calendar could be empty in Huawei?

Comment: @nicopasso, error message in logcat you posted is not responsible for application crash. Exception logs will be tagged with tag AndroidRuntime and not System.err. Please post correct logs.

Comment: So, the line of code you show us is the one indicated here: `at it.mio.miaapp.SplashScreenActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivity.java:225)`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right but this is only log. I don't have any crash log but the app doesn't work at all.

Comment: @nicopasso, In that case crash must be in internal library. Run app with following logcat filter and post stacktrace. adb logcat \*:s AndroidRuntime:\* dalvikvm:*

Comment: I also encounter problems on Huawei, my app crashes when running multiple asynctasks at the same time, with no error message!