# When I try to call LocationClient.connect(), I got NumberFormatException

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I download the project example from google(LocationUpdates.zip, http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).
When I ran it, it showed the exception as follows, but not always:

```
08-10 16:10:34.119: W/System.err(26914): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at java.util.Calendar.getHwFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.java:807)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at java.util.Calendar.<init>(Calendar.java:745)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:338)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:325)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Time.getDecodedObject(ASN1Time.java:44)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1UTCTime.decode(ASN1UTCTime.java:82)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Choice.decode(ASN1Choice.java:308)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.BerInputStream.readSequence(BerInputStream.java:554)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.DerInputStream.readSequence(DerInputStream.java:105)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Sequence.decode(ASN1Sequence.java:40)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.BerInputStream.readSequence(BerInputStream.java:554)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.DerInputStream.readSequence(DerInputStream.java:105)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Sequence.decode(ASN1Sequence.java:40)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.BerInputStream.readSequence(BerInputStream.java:554)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.DerInputStream.readSequence(DerInputStream.java:105)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Sequence.decode(ASN1Sequence.java:40)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Type.decode(ASN1Type.java:91)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:102)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertFactoryImpl.getCertificate(X509CertFactoryImpl.java:656)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertFactoryImpl.engineGenerateCertificate(X509CertFactoryImpl.java:109)
08-10 16:10:34.127: W/System.err(26914):    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:195)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a(Unknown Source)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.p.connect(Unknown Source)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.connect(Unknown Source)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at com.example.android.location.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:197)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
08-10 16:10:34.135: W/System.err(26914):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the code is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    LocationListener,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

// A request to connect to Location Services
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

// Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
......
}
......
public void onStart() {

    Log.i(TAG, "onStart of MainActivity");
    super.onStart();

    /*
     * Connect the client. Don't re-start any requests here;
     * instead, wait for onResume()
     */
    Log.i(TAG, "connect() of LocationClient begin");
    mLocationClient.connect();
    Log.i(TAG, "connect() of LocationClient finish");

}
```

The exception is because the sentence:

```
mLocationClient.connect();
```

there is also another project when I try to new a MimeMessage, it throw a exactly the same exception: NumberFormatException:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
```

In fact, In my projects, there are many scenarios where throw out this kinds of exception even I didn't operate a number/time related variable.
This guy has same problem with me.
[Android error in java InputStreamReader only with Huawei phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936086/android-error-in-java-inputstreamreader-only-with-huawei-phone)

I struggled with this exception for many days. I don't know why. Hope some android experts can help me. Thanks to you all.
My mobile is Huawei Ascend D1 dual.

Comment: i have added an answer, let me know if u have trouble ?

Comment: and try to ask only one question at a time

Answer (score 0):

You may need to declare `LocationClient mLocationClient;` **as class variable**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sorry I declared the mLocationClient in the project but I didn't paste it out.

Comment: I modified the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have declared the mLocationClient varialble alright, but you didn't initialize it before calling another method (the mLocationClient.connect() method) on it.

Try adding this to your code.

```
mLocationClient = new LocationClient();
```

This will initialize the variable before calling that method on it.

If that has been taken care of, then know that at the point where you call mLocationClient.connect(), if mLocationClient is null, it will give you an error. So you need to put in place a condition which sets up mLocationClient if its null before connecting. For instance

```
public void onStart() {

    Log.i(TAG, "onStart of MainActivity");
    super.onStart();

    /*
     * Connect the client. Don't re-start any requests here;
     * instead, wait for onResume()
     */
    Log.i(TAG, "connect() of LocationClient begin");

    //Checks to see if LocationClient is not set and then sets it
    setUpLocationClientIfNull();
    mLocationClient.connect();
    Log.i(TAG, "connect() of LocationClient finish");

}

//And now the method to set up mLocationClient if its null
private void setUpLocationClientIfNull() {
   if (mLocationClient == null) {
       mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
   } 
}
```

This makes sure mLocationClient is set before calling the mLocationClient.connect() method.

Comment: thanks for you reply. This project is downloaded form google. The mLocationClient has been initialized in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

The Certificate the server is using for SSL does not fully follow the X.509 standard, and the Apache Harmony certificate parser breaks, since it's expecting an ASN.1 UTCTime and its founding a different type.

It you cannot replace the server certificate, you'll need to use your own SSL handshake implementation instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I changed the mobile. It runs perfectly on other devices. It seems it is the problem related to some device.